# Showing annotations in exported map in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, annotation

I have a problem to export a map with annotations in QGIS 3.4.
I create annotations in the visor, but when exporting the map, this shows with other size.
What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: How do you define the size of your labels: points, pixels, millimeters, meters at scale?

Comment: The layer labels are showed good, but the option "ANNOTATION THE TEXT" doesnt represent correcly the scale. In the next links you can see it. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/swurst6957nfn8w/AABQS2gXCHn-2P-siDa2vK-_a?dl=0

Comment: the annotationtext will get small if you have a higher resolution in your image or print out. If you lower the resolution like 96dpi (screen) it will have the same size. If you need a scale independent annotation, use labels instead of annotations.

Comment: I am using a resolution of 300 dpi, but in the other version I use the same and I was not had this problem. You recommend that I use label instead of annotation but this option cant show charter bubbies like the example......